# Maximum Likelihood Estimation with Poisson distribution

Tags: poisson-distribution, maximum-likelihood, log-likelihood

We have two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with $X\sim Poisson(\Phi)$ and $Y\sim Poisson(2\Phi)$, and the observations $x=2$ and $y=4$ of these.

Show that the expression for the log-likelihood function is given by:

**$l(\phi)=[4ln(2)-ln(2!)-4ln(4!)]+6ln(\phi)-3ln(\phi)$**

---

I know that the function for Poisson distribution is given by:

Probability mass function: $P(X = k) = \frac{\lambda ^k}{k!}e^{-\lambda}$

Standard Normal Distribution: $Z=\frac{X-\lambda}{\sqrt{\lambda}} $

Log Likelihhod: $ln[f(x_1,x_2,...,x_n;p)]$

But how do I use these to show the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pmf of a poisson $Po(\phi)$ is

$$P(X=x)=\frac{e^{-\phi}\phi^x}{x!}$$

but as the likelihood depends on the parameter $\phi$ we can say also that

$$L(\theta)\propto e^{-\phi}\phi^x$$

Thus your likelihood becomes

$$L(\phi)\propto e^{-\phi}\phi^2e^{-2\phi}(2\phi)^4$$

taking its log, after some easy algebraic manipulations you get

$$l(\phi)=-3\phi+6\log\phi$$

This expression is equivalent to the one you are requesting to show as loglikelihoods are equivalent but an additive constant (the expression in your [ ] brackets)

Of course there is an evident typo in your statement: your $-3\log(\phi)$ is evidently $-3\phi$... mine is correct!